# Create a path in mapping software and export as vector?

Tags: vector, cartography, route

Is it possible to map a route in any mapping software (OpenStreetMaps, Google Maps/Earth, QGIS, etc. preferably Open Source or free) and export this route as a vector (PDF, AI, SVG etc.)?

I'm only interested in the route taken (as a line), without any other information.

Comment: yes. but, of course, the main point of using any GIS is the underlying coordinate reference. please explain what exactly your plan is, where that line comes from and where you want it to go. or why you can't just draw a line in GIMP/Inkscape...,)

Comment: Are you asking to export a route generated through a routing algorithm (like when you search for driving directions in Google Maps), or do you simply want to draw the line by hand over a map?